# how to get the entire text inside "" multi selected in vscode in a macbook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

In sublime, I can select the whole text inside the qoutation using (ctrl+shift+.) even in multi selection. how ca i do it on vscode?

example:

```
<div className="App-testing">
<header className="App-header">
```

if i click the cursor in the strings inside '"' using (alt+click),
the cursor is inside both in strings. if I (ctrl+shift+.), the whole strings is selected. How can I do it in vscode?

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> to put additional cursors where you want them in vscode.

Then use the [expand-region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region) extension (defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> I believe after you install the extension)  to select everything within the quotes wherever your cursors are.  Depending on the complexity of the text you may need to hit the keychord more than once.

This works very well.

---

Or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Click</kbd> inside your strings and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> now seems to work better than before.

[I assume for a mac it is `Cmd` instead of `Ctrl`.]